# mysql query - show last month's data unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I have made this query and it works correct to show data for a month from the current date. For example this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 WHERE price >=100 
  AND active = 1 
  AND dateadded >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
ORDER BY testvalue DESC
```

This query outputs date time stamp from i.e.30th October till the current date 30th November. I have edited the query and takeout `CURDATE` but it fails at the point.

The question is how would I change this query to just show only last months i.e. October's data if the month is November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the range between the first day of the previous month, which you can get by formatting the date and setting the day part to `01` and the last day of the previous month. There's a [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) for that. On the same page in the manual you also find information about `DATE_FORMAT()`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test 
 WHERE price >=100 
  AND active = 1 
  AND dateadded BETWEEN 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01')) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), ' 23:59:59'))
ORDER BY testvalue DESC
```

Comment: This is a good strategy but it chops off results from the last day of the month, since it's between the start of the first day of the month and start of the last day of the month.  

the second part should be AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01'))

Comment: Thanks for spotting this error, but I'm afraid yours isn't correct 100% either. Since `BETWEEN` is including, you actually have to take the end of the previous day. I fixed my answer regarding this. And when you subtract 0 month, you might as well not subtract anything at all. But thanks again for noticing and notifying me.

Comment: So my update would show orders from the first second of the next month.  Ok, nice update, thanks.

Comment: You have a new typo. UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), ' 23:59:59')) should be UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), ' 23:59:59')), you're missing a closing parenthesis.